# Sending Data To A Server With With Siemens MC55

Tags: gprs, at-command

I want to send some pictures for a sever with a GPRS Module. At first i had a sim900 module and I could send data with it with these AT commands:

```
at+cgatt=1;+cstt="myapn";+ciicr;
at+cipstart="tcp","ip","port"
```

As I said with these commands I could send some data to my test server. But it encountered some problems and i've changed it with a Siemens **MC55 GPRS Modem**. But I can't run these commands any more for connecting to my server and i get ERROR.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT data connection commands are inherently different from modem to modem. Do you have a copy of the user manual? The user manual is extremely good for the MC55i!

As a side note execute:

```
AT+CMEE=1
```

To improve the error reporting so that you get real error codes and not just ERROR